# Failed to change the appbar backgroud color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, appbar

I use https://codesandbox.io/s/github/SabuShakya/React-Sidebar-Using-Material-UI/ one as reference,
i want to update the background of appbar to #ffb74d,

I have checked lots of answers, the answer works for me in other project I tried,but the same method can't help in this one, I don't know what's wrong here

The following code is what I added in MiniDrawer.js, it doesn't work as expected

```
    const theme = createMuiTheme({
      palette: {
        primary: {
          // Purple and green play nicely together.
          main: '#0fb7ae',
        },
        secondary: {
          // This is green.A700 as hex.
          main: '#11cb5f',
        },
      },
    });


....
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <AppBar
                position="fixed"
                color={theme.palette.primary.main}
.......
```

Anyone help me out ?

Comment: can you provide a snippet of your code please ?

Comment: added the code what I tired

Comment: just change color to backgroundColor and it will do the trick. By putting color only the element inside gonna change of color like the text or icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try this for Appbar background color**

[image]